# What's the equivalent of `imagesdir` for other asset files in Asciidoctor.js?

Tags: asciidoctor, hexo

I have a blog post written as an .adoc with my `:imagesdir:` set to blank (because the Hexo blogging system sets the post's relative url to the asset subfolder).

All my images load correctly, that's great. E.g.

`image::patcher.png[]`

But when I try to link to another file in my post's folder like

`link:++animation.blend++[Blender project file]`

the link is provided from the root of my site (incorrect).

How do I specify the root post folder for asset files, like I do the imagesdir folder for images please?

Answer (score 0):

I asked on the github page too: https://github.com/hcoona/hexo-renderer-asciidoc/issues/9

For the moment, raw HTML is a workaround:

`++++
<a href='animation.blend'>Blender project file</a>
++++`